# can uberRUSH drivers be given instructions

Tags: uber-api

Is it possible with UberRUSH to give drivers a simple errand before delivery such as go to shop 'x' and buy 'y', then deliver it to address 'z'? Provided that the payment for 'y' is provided as part of the payment.

Comment: Doesn't sound viable. Would it be the responsibility of the caller to verify that the item is in stock at the shop? At what point should the driver stop walking around looking for an item that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

No, UberRush provides on-demand delivery only. If the task is a simple note for how to pickup you can specify - talk to reception, go to floor x, but not actual tasks..